# Customizing & finding intersection points in polar plot

Tags: plotting

I want to verify a theory stating that a golden mean spiral plotted on a polar graph will have intersection points at specific values.

[image: golden mean spiral plotted on polar graph]

There should be 8 concentric circles, each **at the same distance** as the previous one. The radial lines should be in 10-degree increments, and the spiral should start from `0` on the first circle in the middle and end on circle #8 at `360`.

The golden mean spiral should progress independently of the grid lines. If all these requirements are met, `NSolve` should reveal where the intersection points are (the theory claims
 - 0deg at circle #1
 - 120deg at circle #2
 - 190deg at circle #3
 - 240deg at circle #4
 - 280deg at circle #5
 - 360deg at circle #8).

If the initial stretch of the spiral proves the theory wrong, trying to stretch the spiral between any 2 intersection points might do it.

[image]

Comment: That's not a golden spiral.  This might be `PolarPlot[GoldenRatio^(2 n/\[Pi]), {n, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]`.  Can you quote or link to the theorem?

Comment: Once properly normalized, the 120, 240, and 360 crossings are correct as stated. This is because the exponents for 2,4,8 are in ratio 1,2,3. The other crossings that you give are only approximately on target. For 3rd one it comes to around 190.2, and 5th is at 278.63 degrees. 6th is 310.2.

Comment: Is it possible to show this on the graphic?

Comment: Please do not edit it just to add "Unsolved" or "Solved". We don't do status updates here. If an answer has solved your problem, you can accept it by clicking the tick mark/check mark.

Answer (score 8):

Here's my attempt at the graph.

```
radial = Range[10, 360, 10] /. {
 120 :> {120, Black}, 190 :> {190, Black}, 240 :> {240, Black}, 
 280 :> {280, Black}, 360 :> {360, Black}
 } /. k_Integer :> k Degree;
circular = GoldenRatio^(2 {0, 120, 190, 240, 280, 320, 360} Degree/π);

PolarPlot[GoldenRatio^(2 n/π), {n, 0, 2 π}, 
  PolarAxes -> {True, False}, PolarTicks -> Range[0, 350, 10] Degree, 
  PolarGridLines -> {radial, circular}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: golden]

I'm still not convinced about the theorem though.

Comment: The theorem is from a book I read some time ago, I'll search to see if it's published somewhere online. The golden mean spiral should progress from its starting point independently of the grid lines (maybe a second rule would be to finish at 360 on the 8th circle, not 7th). We are checking to see at which angles it intersects the circular grid lines (with `NSolve`?); these angles are afterwards emphasized as radial black lines.

Comment: Right now the code doesn't reflect the problem correctly. The circles are built on top of the spiral and the distance between them is not equal.

Comment: That's why I'd like to know exactly what the theorem is.  As far as I can tell, the curve does not go through equally spaced points at those angles (aside from my ability to count to eight).

Comment: This is exactly the theorem, you got it right: allegedly, the curve goes through equally spaced circles at those angles. This may be untrue, but I can't prove it; I just began learning Mathematica. And it is a wild ride!

Answer (score 4):

Here you can control the axes quite nicely:

```
tickmarks = Range[0, 350, 10];
circles = Range[0, 200, 18];
ListPolarPlot[Table[GoldenRatio*n, {n, 100}], Joined -> True, 
      PolarAxes -> {True, False}, 
      PolarTicks -> {tickmarks Degree, Automatic},
      PolarGridLines -> {tickmarks Degree, circles}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Control the locations of the ticks using the variable `tickmarks` and the location of the circles using the variable `circles`.

Comment: There should be 8 radial grid lines; `circles = Range[0, 200, 20]` approximates it. The spiral should start from the 0 edge of first circle (radial grid). I'm not sure if this is really a golden mean logarithmic spiral. We need to check whether this spiral intersects the circular grid lines at nodes where the circular and radial lines also intersect. I guess that in order to do this, we'll have to also define that the spiral should end at 360 on the outermost circle (radial grid #8).

Comment: I wasn't trying to prove or reprove the theorem, but to give control over the axes... btw -- the increments in the Range don't need to be integers.

Comment: Using the `GoldenRatio^(2 n/π), {n, 0, 2 π}` from the other answer complicates even more what I have until now. Also, I'm racking my brains trying to move the spiral starting point on the first circle with no luck...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that we don't know the definition of this "Golden Mean spiral"

I think here
$$
r(\theta) = 8^\frac{\theta}{2\pi}
$$

```
r[t_] := 8^(t/(2 π));
tickmarks = Range[0, 350, 10];
circles = Range[8];
angles = {120, 190, 240, 280} Degree;

PolarPlot[r[t], {t, 0, 2 π}, PolarAxes -> Automatic, 
 PolarTicks -> {tickmarks Degree, Automatic}, 
 PolarGridLines -> {Join[tickmarks Degree, {#, Red} & /@ angles], circles}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Point[{r[#] Cos[#], r[#] Sin[#]} & /@ angles]}]
```

[image]

Points at $120^{\circ}$ and $240^{\circ}$ have exact matching

```
r[120. Degree]
r[240. Degree]
```

> 2
>
> 4

However, angles $190^{\circ}$ and $280^{\circ}$ isn't exact

```
r[190. Degree]
r[280. Degree]
```

> 2.99661
>
> 5.03968

Comment: I'm not sure what the formula for representing it is, but the Golden Mean curve is a logarithmic spiral having as exponent the `GoldenRatio` or `"\[Phi]"`: `(1 + Sqrt[5])/2`   http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoldenSpiral.html

Comment: @Bogdan I know, but in your book definition may be different. I solve equation for $120^\circ$-point and get $8$ as exponent.

Comment: The code doesn't correspond with the drawing, the spiral is missing. Assuming we have the right Golden spiral, can the intersection points be represented on the graphic?

Comment: @Bogdan Sorry, there was a typo: not `f[t]` but `r[t]`. Of course, see update.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! This looks just like the original drawing, but is that actually a Golden Mean spiral? It is logarithmic indeed, but it doesn't seem to get wider (or further from its origin) by a factor of φ for every quarter turn it makes.

Answer (score 1):

Using `MeshFunctions` for the intersection points in @wxffles's answer:

```
PolarPlot[GoldenRatio^(2 n/π), {n, 0, 2 π}, 
 PolarAxes -> {True, False}, PolarTicks -> Range[0, 350, 10] Degree, 
 PolarGridLines -> {radial, circular}, PlotRange -> All, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{120, 190, 240, 280, 360} Degree}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]
```

[image]